# Does there exist a prime number form of $37\underbrace{11\cdots1}_{n\text{ times}}3$ or $37\underbrace{55\cdots5}_{n\text{ times}}1$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Does there exist a prime number form of $37\underbrace{11\cdots1}_{n\text{ times}}3$ or $37\underbrace{55\cdots5}_{n\text{ times}}1$?

If there is any prime number that is form of $37\underbrace{11\cdots1}_{n\text{ times}}3$, then $n$ must be not:

- $2\pmod{3}$, as the number will be divisible by $3$.
- $4\pmod{6}$, as the number will be divisible by $7$.
- $1\pmod{6}$, as it will be divisible by $13$.

If $37\underbrace{55\cdots5}_{n\text{ times}}1$ is ever a prime number, then $n$ must satisfy one of the following:

- If the number of $5’s$ are odd, then the number will be divisible by $11$. So $n$ must be even.
- $n$ shouldn’t be equal to $2\pmod{3}$, as the number will be divisible by $3$.
- The number of $5’s$ must not be divisible by $6$ in order to not divisble
- by $7$.
- $n$ must not be equal to $8\pmod{16}$, in order to be not divisible by $17$.

Using Pari GP, I tried to check the values of $n\leq10^{4}$ to check if there is any prime number in this number form, but I wasn’t succesful.

Is there a prime number that is form of :

$37\underbrace{11\cdots1}_{n\text{ times}}3$

$37\underbrace{55\cdots5}_{n\text{ times}}1$

Comment: Your title is different from your question

Comment: Primes cannot equal $0$ or $6$ $\mod 9$ so therefore, for $37\underbrace{11\cdots1}_{n\text{ times}}3$, $n$ cannot be $2$ or $5$ $\mod 9$, and for $37\underbrace{55\cdots5}_{n\text{ times}}1$ we have that $5n$ cannot be $4$ or $7$ $\mod 9$

Comment: For the first, try $n=697$.

Comment: For the first one: isn't $371111111111111113$ ($n = 15$) prime? (Also $n = 84$, $n = 697$, $n = 900$..). For the second one: I think $n$ has to be even, in fact - and it must be $4$ modulo $6$ as otherwise it will be divisible by at least one of $3, 7, 11$. I don't know the answer though!

Comment: If $n$ (the number $5$s) is odd (not even), then $37\underbrace{55\cdots5}_{n\text{ times}}1$ is divisible by $11$. So, $n$ must be even (not odd). Please replace "even" with "odd" and vice versa.

Comment: $373$ is prime; do you count $n=0$?

Comment: Interesting , but please edit the title to make it consistent.

Comment: The formula for the second case is $\frac{169*2^{n+2}*5^{n+1}-41}{9}$ , upto $n=9\ 300$ , I found no prime.

Comment: How did you come up with this question?

Answer (score 1):

A probable prime of the second type :

[factordb](http://www.factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000005692685054)

It will be hard to prove the primality.

$$\frac{5^{13385}\cdot 2^{13386}\cdot 169-41}{9}$$ with $13387$ digits

Comment: This corresponds to $n=13384$, right?

Comment: @Sahaj Correct.